# How to trigger a function of sibling component without Prop Drilling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So as you can see in image i do have this structure of components.

```
<Invoice>
  <Left></Left>
  <Right></Right>
</Invoice>
```

I do have a Form in Left component and Submit button in Right component (Send Invoice). so i want to submit form when i click on Send invoice button, with using Context API ? (Not using props)

How do i do that ?

[image]

Comment: Where is the form data stored, in the local state of the left component?

Comment: All data is in left. right just have one button.

Comment: To avoid prop drilling use the react [context provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). The answer to this question is a lot of basic code to write a context provider. Please learn it from [react](https://reactjs.org)

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the Send invoice button you can toggle a Boolean flag in your React context implementation and in your Left Component check if that Boolean flag set to true and call the function that handles your form submit.

Comment: Well yes i tried this solution, the problem is when i am doing that it reloads the page. 

`useEffect( () => {
       if (submitForm){
            fooForm.current.submit();
       }
    })` I have added `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` on form, and doing `e.preventDefault();` in this function. but still it reloads.

Comment: because you are triggering it using  fooForm.current.submit(). try adding a ref to the submit button and calling the click function on it.

Comment: i do have that solution working already, and i do find this less techy, its more trick rather actual solution. ideally i would like to trigger submit action on clicking send invoice button, no middleman.